# How to know which theme is causing a particular attribute value in a View?

Tags: android

In my textview the textColor attribute is not specified, hence it is applying a default value. Is there a way to find out that which theme or style is causing that text color ?

Comment: in manifest !!!

Comment: I have the theme name from manifest, but how do i know which textcolor is it using?

Comment: getCurrentTextColor()

Comment: @mohamed thanks but i need a list of it hence looking for documentation could not find one